# Instagram API created_time to date with Moment.js

Tags: javascript, json, instagram-api

I want to parse the string JSON object of created_time from the Instagram API into a readable date. I've read several posts saying that `new Date("1923111")` (whatever created_time is) will solve this issue, but I'm getting back an invalid date error.

I want to use Moment.js to parse it as such:

```
moment.unix(created_time).format("MMMM D, YYYY")
```

but I'm receiving `1469576855000-20en` as an output. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: The above code is working totally for me. I am assuming that `1469576855000` is unix timestamp in miliseconds. loading `1469576855` to `moment.unix(m).format("MMMM D, YYYY")` returns the date.

Comment: I'm passing in created_time as a JSON string on the backend, does it have to do with that? Does it have to be an int?

Comment: Can you post your full code?

Comment: Partial code: https://jsfiddle.net/s961cbe2/

Comment: Solved. Looks like it was a typo on my end.

Answer (score 1):

```
var date = new Date(image.created_time*1000);

 m = date.getMonth();
 d = date.getDate();
 y = date.getFullYear();

var month_names = new Array ( );
month_names[month_names.length] = "01";
month_names[month_names.length] = "02";
month_names[month_names.length] = "03";
month_names[month_names.length] = "04";
month_names[month_names.length] = "05";
month_names[month_names.length] = "06";
month_names[month_names.length] = "07";
month_names[month_names.length] = "08";
month_names[month_names.length] = "09";
month_names[month_names.length] = "10";
month_names[month_names.length] = "11";
month_names[month_names.length] = "12";

var thetime = y + '-' + month_names[m] + '-' + d;

image.created_time = thetime;

return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var date = new Date(parseInt(created_time) * 1000);

var month = (date.getMonth()+1);
var date = date.getDate();
var fullYear = date.getFullYear();
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!